# An admissible set's graph being triple-edged means it corresponds to $G_2$?

Tags: lie-groups, graphing-functions, coxeter-groups, dynkin-diagrams

Let $\gamma$ be a triple-edged graph that is associated with an admissible set in a real inner product space. Please, how do  I show that $\gamma$ is the Coxeter graph of the Dynkin diagram, $G_2$?